# How to get information about a user by having his token

Tags: php, discord

How can I get some information about the user after his authorization, I need to get a list of his servers. I'm using RestCord and oauth2-discord-new libraries, but these libraries do not allow this. How to do this using php?

#### UPD:

What I tried:

```
$provider = $discord->provider;
if (!Yii::$app->request->get('code')) {
    $options = [
        'scope' => ['identify', 'email', 'guilds']
    ];
    $authUrl = $provider->getAuthorizationUrl($options);
    return $this->redirect($authUrl);
} else {
    $token = $provider->getAccessToken('authorization_code', [
        'code' => Yii::$app->request->get('code')
    ]);
    $discord = new DiscordClient(['token' => $token->getToken()]);
    $discord->user->getCurrentUser([]); // Return 401 UNAUTHORIZED
}
```

Comment: There is literally an infinite amount of information missing to diagnose this one.

Comment: @MatheusReis, My code is not required here (but I still updated the question), since this problem is more related to the restcord documentation. I'm not asking you to write a code for me, but I just want to know where i can see the examples and what libraries i can still use if the current one does not give such an opportunity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I looked at the source code of restcord. Also found there parameter `tokenType`. About it nothing is written in the documentation, but if you install it in OAuth then the library will work in user mode and not the bot. How to use it correctly:

```
$discord = new DiscordClient([
    'token' => 'userToken', 
    'tokenType' => 'OAuth'
]);
```

I spent a lot of time looking for a solution to this problem, and I was very surprised that this parameter is not written in the official documentation. I hope this will save you time!

Comment: Yup, still true in 2020. No reference to the `tokenType` parameter in the documentation. Added `'tokenType' => 'OAuth'` and am now able to retrieve user details. Thank you.